# Why Authentication type - individual user accounts for Web API in .NET Core is not available when we creating new Web APi service

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

Why it`s not possible to create Web API project with Individual User Accounts Authorization type?

[image: Screenshot: Change authentication dialog]

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE:**

All version numbers are updated from v1.2 to v2.0.

Please find the [ASP.NET Core Schedule and Roadmap](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap):

> **Identity Application Services**
>
> A service layer will be added ASP.NET Core Identity and included in the project templates using Individual Authentication. This will allow authentication of users by way of JWT tokens such that Web APIs can be secured out of the box, and make it simpler to change authentication systems, e.g. from in-app Identity to Azure AD B2C, or 3rd-party solutions like Identity Server.

Answer (score 8):

Daniel Roth from MS:

Support for individual user accounts with the Web API template in VS is not available yet. We are still looking at providing a supported on premise offering for token issuance in addition to providing integration with Azure AD B2C.

This statement can be found in the comment section under https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/dotnetConf/2016/Building-Secure-Web-APIs-with-ASPNET-Core

Answer (score 0):

This is just disabled in core 1.1.please use core 2.0 to find all authentication.You can download core 2.0 from 
[here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/windows)