# Individual User Authentication on ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I can see from this post: [Why Authentication type - individual user accounts for Web API in .NET Core is not available when we creating new Web APi service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213422/why-authentication-type-individual-user-accounts-for-web-api-in-net-core-is-n)

That individual user authentication is not enabled yet... But is there an alternative as I need to build a mobile app and I have a lot of users registered through the web app?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you can use jwt: https://jwt.io/

Comment: @Alex Thanks, Would that allow me to use default tables created by ASP.NET Core identity like ASPNetUsers? Do you have any samples?

Comment: I don't have jwt experience yet. Please look: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jwt/5213/getting-started-with-jwt#t=201702221850350232262 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

Comment: @Alex I see that IdentityServer is recommended..... any suggestions on implementation?

Comment: yes, I see you asked other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42415026/webapi-identityserver-on-asp-net-core-project Unfortunately I don't have experience with it neither. That's why I decided to go with web application instead web api, because it's easy to implement authentication.